# Best way to change large amount of String Columns to integers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

When I read in my data I get all my columns as string type, I believe due to null values in the data. After replacing the nulls with '0' I have a large sparse dataset of 1000 columns with 0's and 1's of string type.

I believe in order to get this to run any ML algorithms I need to use `VectorAssembler`, which requires numeric types. What is the best way to change this entire dataset of string 0s and 1s to integer type?

Can I use `stringIndexer` to replace the 1000 columns? I am having trouble with syntax to do that. Or should I use 'cast'?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Is the data from a csv file? Did you set `inferSchema` to true when reading it?